# How to connect with the Metamask and Coinbase wallet separately in DAPP?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, coinbase

I facing an issue while connecting in Metamask and Coinbase wallet. The issue is when I try to connect with Metamsk wallet it will open Coinbase extension. I think when both Metamask and Coinbase wallet was installed, Metamsk wallet was overridden by the  Coinbase wallet. How to add separate wallet connect function for these Metamsk and Coinbase wallets.

these are the code sample now I'm using

```
export const GetWallet = async () => {
  if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
    if (window.ethereum.isMetamask) {
      if (await window.ethereum._metamask.isUnlocked()) {
        return "metamask"; // Wallet is Metamask.
      } else {
        throw Error("not-unlocked");
      }
    }else{
      return "unknown"; // Wallet is Coinbase. Logic not complete here
    }
  } else {
    throw Error("non-ethereum"); 
  }
};
```

**Unlock wallet function**

```
  const unlockWallet = async () => {
        await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
        history.goBack();
    };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using chrome extensions, you can access to each provider using
`window.ethereum.providers`
You can try `console.log(window.ethereum.providers`

Therefore, you can choose to connect Metamask or Coinbase Wallet with

```
let walletProvider = window.ethereum.providers.find((x) => x.isMetaMask) // isMetamask is part of the injected provider

... = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(walletProvider)
```

same for Coinbase

```
let walletProvider = window.ethereum.providers.find((x) => x.isCoinbaseWallet) // isCoinbaseWallet is part of the injected provider

... = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(walletProvider)
```